# Scroll questions in 10k-tools

Tags: feature-request, support, 10k-tools

I have been reviewing posts with flags of late having gotten access to the 10k-tools. Though there is the pull-down to resize how much of the question is displayed, I sometimes need to resize quite a few times to get the whole question on the page because of the size of the post. This ends up being tedious and frustrating. This happens especially when I review flags on answers to that question.

Would it be simple/easy/feasible to implement a scrollbar so that reviewers may scroll through the body of the question in a smaller pull-down window and thereby being able to see both the question and the flagged answer to it on the same page?

Comment: That annoys me too quite often. A scrollbar (or what about a popup?) would help.

Comment: I agree. Congrats on the 10k, by the way :)

Comment: @DanielFischer: I hope the popup idea was sarcasm. A widget (like Google Chat) would be better IMO

Comment: Thank you @AndrewBarber

Comment: @inspectorG4dget A popup like when you visit a question with a suggested edit pending. You click the edit link, and up pops the diff. I'm not particularly fond of them, but they're miles better (IMO) than the current drag-the-bar-down-five-miles-inch-by-inch we now have in the tools.

Comment: @DanielFischer: agreed! Sorry, I'm purging a bunch of bloatware from a lab computer right now, so popup meant annoying browser "meet singles" style popups. I fully support your meaning of popup, though

Comment: Oh, commiserations. (And congratulations on becoming a member of the nag-tag squad.)

Comment: Thank you, and thanks @DanielFischer